# Node.js RSS module

Tags: rss, node.js

Is there a way to read from an RSS feed using Node.js, possibly, in Real-time?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/blog/2010/07/26/deliver-real-time-information-to-your-users-using-node-js/). It's a real-time RSS parser tutorial. Enjoy.

Answer (score 28):

try [node-feedparser](https://github.com/danmactough/node-feedparser)

Answer (score 4):

Try [node-rss](https://github.com/ibrow/node-rss). It is unstable though but you should be able to use it as an example to write your own RSS parser.

```
/**********************************************************************
Example One:
Getting a remote RSS feed and parsing
rss.parseURL(feed_url, use_excerpt, callback);
**********************************************************************/
// URL of the feed you want to parse
var feed_url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/github';

var response = rss.parseURL(feed_url, function(articles) {
    sys.puts(articles.length);
    for(i=0; i<articles.length; i++) {
    sys.puts("Article: "+i+", "+
         articles[i].title+"\n"+
         articles[i].link+"\n"+
         articles[i].description+"\n"+
         articles[i].content
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this parses rss,atom and feedburner as well

https://github.com/tk120404/node-rssparser

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about realtime.. I have seen most people poll the RSS URLs using SetTimeout like the example below..

```
function updateFeeds() {
    // Do some work.  Possibly async
    // Call done() when finished.
}

function done() {
    setTimeout( updateFeeds, 1000 * 60 );
}
```

Or you could try using a Task Queue like [Node-Resque](https://github.com/jbr/node-resque).

But here are a couple of libraries that you could source from..

[A simple node.js rss parser using sax-js](http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/a-simple-node-js-rss-parser-using-sax-js/)
or 
[Node FeedParser](https://github.com/danmactough/node-feedparser)

I found a pretty good intro to Node JS that includes a RSS parsing example.. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339740/Know-JavaScript-use-node-js-server-side)

As I make my way through my project, I will update this answer with any new findings.. Hope this helped.